# Pinnacle Game Profiler

Tags: keyboard, games

I have used pinnacle game profiler to play games on windows using a xbox 360 controller but i can't seem to see if pinnacle works on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Welcome to Ask ubuntu! IMO your question doesn't have requisite information for us to answer. Please give us more info about your Ubuntu version and your desktop environemnt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not. It is software that has a license so there if their website does not supply a debian installer there will be none.

Alternatives:

- [antimicro](https://github.com/Ryochan7/antimicro)
- [qjoypad](http://qjoypad.sourceforge.net/) (it is in the repositories so: `sudo apt-get install qjoystick`)
- [gleanstick](http://freecode.com/projects/gleanstick)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know Rinzwind. That's a shame, ill email them asking for a debian installer on their website.